# Where is the root directory of tensorflow installed when using it via Docker on windows?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to find out exactly where TensorFlow is installed when using it with the docker as I want to use the Inception-V3 image classifier to classify my own images. However, the tutorial on the website assumes I installed it using pip and thus I am stuck using the default image. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is.

Can you run these two lines to find out?

import tensorflow
print tensorflow.__file__

Are you currently able to use Inception classifier to classify default images? Can you modify the file path to redirect to your own images?

Comment: Basically, I'm asking how to use the Inception V3 to recognize my own images when it's installed via docker as opposed to being installed via pip. I haven't been able to find any tutorials yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details about tensorflow by typing `pip show tensorflow` from windows command line or powershell.

For me it showed the following details:

```
Name: tensorflow

Version: 0.12.1 

Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow 

Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/ 

Author: Google Inc.    

Author-email: opensource@google.com License: Apache 2.0 

Location:    c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 

Requires: protobuf,    numpy, six, wheel
```